# creating dataframe from csv file having lists as entries in one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `csv` file which looks like this -

```
id  genres
1   [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
2   [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
3   [1,2,3]
4   [{'id':31, 'name':'Comedy'}]
```

When I import the `csv` as `dataframe`, the `lists` in `genres` column are loaded as strings. For example - `"[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]"`

How do I load the `lists` without the `quotes`?

Comment: use the `ast` module. `ast.literal_eval()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import ast, json

df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Or:

```
df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(json.loads)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also using strip()+split():

```
df['genres']= [x.strip("[]").split(',') for x in df['genres']]
```

or,

```
df['genres']= df['genres'].apply(lambda x: x.strip("[]").split(','))
```